# Fill only one half of a display in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to Pygame and I wish to fill only certain parts of my screen, for example the half. Currently I am only able to fill the complete screen. Can someone help?

```
import pygame
color= (255, 0, 0)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((740, 780))
screen.fill(color)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2nd parameter of [`.fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) is a rectangle, which defines the area to be filled.
The width and height of a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object can be get by [`.get_width()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_width) respectively [`.get_height()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_height):

e.g.

```py
screen.fill(color, (0, 0, screen.get_width()// 2, screen.get_height()))
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you remember our conversation from the other thread? I try to figure out, how to update font dynamically in one half of the screen and in the other half, the font updates, but elements stay and not get replaced. So, in the dynamic part, i fill up the screen and in the static part, the screen stays. Not sure if that will help.

Comment: Just opened another question. Maybe you can help me again. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
import pygame

size = w,h = 300, 400
scr = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello")
scr.fill((0,255,0), rect=(0,0,w,h/2))
pygame.display.flip()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            running = False
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to have partial fill may include "drawing" a shape (i.e. rectangle) on half of the screen.

```
import sys

import pygame

def half_screen():
    #Initialize game and create screen object.
    pygame.init()
    color= (255, 0, 0)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 400))
    #Draw rectangle to fill the left half of the screen.
    left_half = pygame.draw.rect(screen, color,(0,0, 100, 400))

    #Start loop for game- keeps screen open until you decide to quit.
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        #Make the current screen visible.
        pygame.display.flip()

half_screen()
```

You can find more information on the draw module - pygame.draw - by going to https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html

Comment: pygame.draw.rect() is very slow. Using screen.fill() with a rect argument is in my epxerience much much faster when you don't need alpha blending or other special flags.